# VB.NET Windows Forms context menu position

Tags: vb.net, properties, datagridview, position, contextmenu

I am enhancing a previously written VB.NET WIndows forms application.

In one of the forms, there is a DataGridView populated from a stored procedure at Form Load.

If the user has the privileges, when the user right clicks on a record in the datagridview, I want to show a context menu allowing the user to delete the record.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub m_SetEnabledContextMenu()
  ' for Delete record
  If Not objUser.HasAuthority("Delete Record") Then
    Me.DataGridView1.ContextMenu = Nothing
    Me.mnuContextEquationSubmission.Enabled = False
  Else
    ' Me.DataGridView1.ContextMenu = Me.mnuContextEquationSubmission
    Me.mnuContextEquationSubmission.Enabled = True
  End If
  'Rest is not problem
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) _
            Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDown
  If e.Button = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
      row.Selected = False
    Next
    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True

    'MessageBox.Show("DataGridView1_CellMouseDown on row " & e.RowIndex.ToString)
    m_intSelRow = e.RowIndex
    m_intSelCol = e.ColumnIndex

    m_strRecordID = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value

    'mnuContextEquationSubmission.Show(DataGridView1, e.Location)
    mnuContextEquationSubmission.Show(CType(sender, Control), e.Location)
  End If
End Sub
```

as you can see, in the procedure 'm_SetEnabledContextMenu' I determine whether of not the user will have the authority to delete records, and thus the context menu will be activated (or at least, that's what I want) - whilst of the user doesn't have the authority, the menu should be invisible and disabled.

In the event handler DataGridView1_CellMouseDown, if it's a right-click and if the user has clicked in a data row, then I want the context menu to display where the mouse is, NOT at the top!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mnuContextEquationSubmission.Show(Me, Me.PointToClient(MousePosition))`